# Read value from query string in CodeIgniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, get, routes

I am new to CodeIgniter. I am trying to read values from query string in conventional method not segment.

**This is my url.**

`http://localhost/Voyager/Main/UserActivation/?u=6df497644a10241cd89fad80f5c98496`

**Controller:**

```
class Main extends CI_Controller{

     public function UserActivation()
    {
        $hash=$this->input->get('u', TRUE);
        log_message('debug', $hash, false); 
        $this->load->view('Main\view_userActivation');  
    }

}
```

I am trying to read value of 'u' in controller. But this isn't working. I am getting empty value in $hash variable.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Codeigniter get parameters from url](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33682673/codeigniter-get-parameters-from-url)

Comment: @DanWhite. If you check properly you will find that one which you mention talks about getting values from segment. Issue which I have mentioned is different. Before taking efforts to ask a question I have scanned more than 4 pages of google search results for issue.

Comment: Your Code should work. Just check you set `$config['allow_get_array'] = TRUE;` at your config.php andmake sure your `url` helper is loaded

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Codeigniter works with URI Segments. You pass the values straight in your URL, separated with **/** and you grab them with positions after base_url like

> $this->uri->segment(3)

Check this link: [Codeigniter Documentation](https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/libraries/uri.html)

Comment: Awesome. This is easiest answer I found for this. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 2):

There's a config option that unsets the `$_GET` array, *but only if you have decided to change it*.
This is how it looks by default in application/config/config.php:

```
$config['allow_get_array'] = TRUE;
```

If you've changed it to `false` - switch it back to `true`. Other than that, there's no reason why this wouldn't work, by default.

Answer (score 1):

you can do something like this

**Method 01**

```
class Main extends CI_Controller{

    public function UserActivation($u)
    {
        echo $u;
        die;
        $this->load->view('Main\view_userActivation');  
    }

}
```

Then URL should be

```
http://localhost/Voyager/Main/UserActivation/6df497644a10241cd89fad80f5c98496
```

---

**Method 02**

```
class Main extends CI_Controller{

    public function UserActivation()
    {
        $value = $this->uri->segment(3);
        echo $value;
        $this->load->view('Main\view_userActivation');  
    }

}
```

Comment: Thank you. Appreciate your effort. )

Comment: ha ha. No issues :)

Comment: Are you sure Method2 will work for the link that OP used?

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `/` from the last uri segment.

`http://localhost/Voyager/Main/UserActivation?u=6df497644a10241cd89fad80f5c98496`

Also, another thing. Why you have your uri controller and methods starting in uppercase? That shouldn't be that way.